# Continuous functions in metric spaces and open sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces, proof-writing

WTS: For two metric spaces $X,Y$ If $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous then for every open set  $U\subset Y$, $f^{-1}(U)$ is open.
May someone please verify if this proof is correct?

> Proof: Assume $f$ is continuous. Let $U$ be an open set in $Y$. Let
>   $x\in f^{-1}(U)$. Since $U$ is open, there exists an $\epsilon>0$ such
>   that $N_{\epsilon}(f(x)) \subset U$. Since the function is continuous,
>   $\exists \delta >0$ such that whenever  $p\in f^{-1}(U)$ and $p\in
>  N_{\delta}(x)$ then $f(p)\in N_{\epsilon}(f(x))$. Since $f(p)\in
>  N_{\epsilon}(f(x))$ then  $p\in f^{-1}(U)$ and so $N_{\delta}(x)
>  \subset U$.

The question I have is that I think the proof is correct, but I don't see why the $p$ cannot be in the intersection of the $N_{\delta}(x)
$. and  $f^{-1}(U)$.

May someone please clarify and tell me what I should do to improve the proof? Please?

Comment: First you assume "Such that whenever $p \in f^{-1}(U)$. . . " which is exactly what you are trying to prove. Try to drop that assumption at the earlier stage of the proof.

Comment: But isn't that what it means to be continuous?

Comment: What is your definition of continuous function? Because for me, what you quote as theorem is the definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have meant to finish with $N_\delta (x) \subset f^{-1}(U)$ instead of $\subset U$. But also  you shouldn't assume that $p\in f^{-1}(U)$ and $p \in N_\delta(x)$ when using continuity of $f$, this is like using continuity of $f$ as a function on the induced metric subspace, $f:f^{-1}(U)\to Y$. Instead, you want to get your small ball $N_\delta(x)\subset X$ and prove that it is a subset of $f^{-1}(U)$.

The inclusion $A \subset f^{-1}(f(A))$ and the implication $B\subset C \implies f^{-1}(B) \subset f^{-1}(C)$, true for any function $f$ and sets $A,B,C$ will be useful.

Comment: For a given function f: X $\rightarrow$ Y is it not the case that if f is continuous for all x in X then f is continuous at any subset of X?

Comment: Correct but not useful when the final goal is to find a ball of X that is completely contained in the pre image @topologicalmagician

Comment: so if x $\in$ X and x$\in$ $N_{\delta}(p)$  then $f(x) \in N_{\epsilon}(f(p))$ , but the issue im having is that I know that x is in the intersection of a ball(nbhd) and X is a metric space but does tha mean that the neighbourhood is a subset of X?

Comment: Sorry can you write that again, x is in the intersection of a ball and...? Remember the point of the exercise is to get that the pre image is open in X @topologicalmagician

Comment: Nevermind, I understood it. Thank you very much!

Comment: @topologicalmagician OK then, glad you got it

Answer (score 0):

> Proof: Assume $f$ is continuous. Let $U$ be an open set in $Y$. Let
>   $x\in f^{-1}(U)$. Since $U$ is open,

and $f(x) \in U$

> there exists an $\epsilon>0$ such
>   that $N_{\epsilon}(f(x)) \subset U$. Since the function is continuous,

using the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ continuity definition at $x$ and our $\epsilon$

> $\exists \delta >0$ such that whenever  $p\in
> N_{\delta}(x)$ then $f(p)\in N_{\epsilon}(f(x))$.

(omit $p \in f^{-1}[U]$ because we have to show it, not assume it)

> Now, if $p$ is such that $p \in N_\delta(x)$ then $f(p)\in
>  N_{\epsilon}(f(x)) \subseteq U$ and so $p\in f^{-1}(U)$ and as $p$ was arbitrary, $N_{\delta}(x)
>  \subset f^{-1}[U]$, and so $x$ is an interior point of $f^{-1}[U]$.